# Synchronize multiple sets of data by date

Tags: excel, vba

What I have is multiple sets of data logs that are timestamped: there's a point of data every 5 sec for example.

It looks like something like this:

```
1 - 06:31:01 - 0.1
2 - 06:31:06 - 0.4
3 - 06:31:11 - 0.3
```

Where the third column is just data

However, sometimes the machine stops logging data for a few minutes, making it hard to have them side-by-side with the time matching, especially if this happens many time over with logs that span half a day!

What i'm looking for is for an algorithm to synchronize the logs in excel using vba excel if necessary.

Comment: A bit more detail on the output you want would help - e.g. do you want something like the result of a SQL `OUTER JOIN` (rows aligned where matching, but blanks in non-matching rows)?

Comment: Is the 1,2,3 the row numbers or are those actual values in a column?

Comment: If I understand correctly what it does OUTER JOIN isn't what i'm looking for. As for the first colomn, yes those are row numbers. MatthewD's code outputs what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references. Select "Microstoft ActiveX data objects 2.8 Library.

This assumes your first list is on sheet 1, second list is on sheet 2, and time is in column A and value is in column B.  It will write data out to sheet 3.

```
Private Sub LineUpLists()
    Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lRow As Long

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.  You can store sums here.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Time", adDouble
        .Fields.Append "Value1", adSingle
        .Fields.Append "Value2", adSingle
        .Open
    End With

    'Read the first list from sheet one.
    lRow = 1
    ws1.Activate
    'Loop through the first list and record what is in the columns
    Do While lRow <= ws1.UsedRange.Rows.count

        If ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
            rs.Fields("Time").Value = Trim(str(ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value))
            rs.Fields("Value1").Value = ws1.Range("B" & lRow).Value
            rs.Update
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    'Read the second list from sheet 2
    lRow = 1
    ws2.Activate
    'Loop through the second list and record what is in the columns
    Do While lRow <= ws2.UsedRange.Rows.count

        If ws2.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then

            'Check if we already recorded this time in the first list
            rs.Filter = ""
            rs.Filter = "Time=" & Trim(str(ws2.Range("A" & lRow).Value))

            If rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
                'If we already have this time, record the second list value
                rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
                rs.Fields("Time").Value = Trim(str(ws2.Range("A" & lRow).Value))
                rs.Fields("Value2").Value = ws2.Range("B" & lRow).Value
                rs.Update
            Else
                'If we didn't see this time on the first list, create a new record for it.
                rs.AddNew
                rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
                rs.Fields("Time").Value = ws2.Range("A" & lRow).Value
                rs.Fields("Value2").Value = ws2.Range("B" & lRow).Value
                rs.Update
            End If
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws2.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    rs.Filter = ""
    rs.Sort = "Time"

    'Switch to sheet 3
    ws3.Activate
    ws3.Range("B1").Value = "Time"
    ws3.Range("B1").Value = "List1"
    ws3.Range("C1").Value = "List2"

    lRow = 2

    'Here we loop through the data we collected and write it out.
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        ws3.Range("A" & lRow).Value = Format(rs.Fields("Time").Value, "hh:mm:ss")
        ws3.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Value1").Value
        ws3.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Value2").Value
        lRow = lRow + 1
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```